# IBM MQMD header how to distinguish

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, mq

How do I distinguish `MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST` vs `MQMT_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 2):

`MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST` is a range identifier and will never be used in a real message. If you see the value 1 in an MQMD, it **always** means `MQMT_REQUEST`.

So in effect you have `MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST -> MQMT_SYSTEM_LAST` as a reserved range for system `MQMT*` values and `MQMT_APPL_FIRST -> MQMT_APPL_LAST` for application use.