# IBMMQ, under what scenario will MQMD.MsgType=1 be interpreted as MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST instead of MQMT_REQUEST

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using JmsTemplate to send messages to an IBM MQ's local queue. We set MQMD property MsgType to 1, but when viewing the message header from the queue, the value is interpreted as MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST instead of MQMT_REQUEST. Why is that? Is this the reason why the other party's system cannot return the reply message?

We are doing debugging with another system. According to their feedback, they checked our message header in the queue like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Gj9.png)

But based on past experience, our message should look like this (Please focus only on the MsgType field).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T9Oi.png)
And there is no clue as to why these two different situations occur. Their values are both 1, but MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST and MQMT_REQUEST are displayed respectively.

Comment: Please provide more information for what you mean by 'the value is interpreted as'. What is doing the interpretation? If you take a look a the cmqc.h file you will see that both `MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST` and `MQMT_REQUEST` are defined as value `1`. This is not an error, but because they are used for different purposes. In the same way the days of the week may be coded 1-7, and months of the year 1-12.

Comment: This is explained in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460680/ibm-mqmd-header-how-to-distinguish - If you see the value 1 in MQMD then it is `MQMT_REQUEST`

Comment: I have upload image,stronger description，please help me

Comment: Looks like an error in the system that is displaying the message, as JasonE said. That field can not be `MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST`. If the other system is interpreting it as `MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST`,  then that is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is just a flaw in whatever you use to view the header in that it does not realize MQMT_SYSTEM_FIRST is never 'set', it is just a range identifier.

What are you using to view the header?

This question is really a duplicate of [IBM MQMD header how to distinguish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460680/ibm-mqmd-header-how-to-distinguish/64460957#64460957)